# Application requests full control over other applications running in memory

Tags: windows

I'm attempting to install Xilisoft DVD Creator and my firewall (Comodo), or more specifically Defense+, alerts me that x-dvd-creator7.exe is trying to access *.exe (random program running in memory, unrelated to the installing program) in memory. I recieve the following message:

[image: The parent application that is accessing the target application in memory will allow the parent application to fully control the target application. This is a common technique used by many legimate applications as well as various malware. If x-dvd-creator7.exe is one of your everyday applications, then you can allow this request.]

What would be the reason (or technique) behind needing to access all executables running in memory? VLC was just a single instance of the installers requests to access the applications running in memory, it will iterate through every single program I have running. I'm just curious why a legitimate program (from an author I trust) would even care what about else was running. I could understand if it were an anti-debugging method (such as IsDebuggerPresent), but it's not. More over, it allows me to run a debugger (OllyDbg and WinDbg) without a problem.